# QVector with struct - performance + best practise

Tags: c++, struct, enums, qvector

I'm having a set of approximately 150 variables that can have different type (double, bool, array). This set of variables I need to pack into a QVector. Because of type variables vary  I thought of using QVariant.  So far this is my design. What I'm not sure is the performance + the search mechanism of myVariables.

```
enum class VariableEnums{
  VAR1,
  VAR2,
  VAR3
};

struct myVariable{
  VariableEnums var;
  QVariant value;
};

QVector<myVariable> myVariables;
```

The idea is that myVariables will be send to several modules. Each module will find a specific variable and update some other variable. So one module can update variable that will be used by another module. So far regarding searching a specific variable I can think only following:

```
foreach(myVariable *myVar, myVariables{
   if(myVar->var == VariableEnums::VAR1){
    //......
    continue;
   }
}
```

Is there some more effective way to do this? I could use indexOf, but I'm not sure how to use it with a structure.

thanks,
m.

Comment: You have to profile it. That way you will know the performance of this choice on your system. Is it also an option to construct `QVector<bool>`, `QVector<double>`, ... and pass them along as needed. It seems like your code is suffering from amnesia because you knew the type then forgot it.

Comment: Do you associate a distinct type with each of VAR1 to VAR3? If so, why no simply keep three separate lists of values and do work only on values in a specific category? This would not only spare you searching a heterogeneous container but also eliminate the runtime overhead of QVariant. Unless you absolutely need a single heterogeneous container, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing some profiling it turned out that QVector with a struct of enums was the fastest combination.  QVector

I have tried QHash, QMap and for data holders QString and QVariant

benchmark:

```
...searching in dataset size:  1090000 
testing < QVector<struct enum> > case time (ms): 242 
testing < QVector<struct QString> > case time (ms): 1220 
testing < QMap<enum, QVariant> > case time (ms): 3458 
testing < QHash<enum, QVariant> > case time (ms): 2167
```

Answer (score 0):

you could consider using multimap instead of QVector. With multimap you can map your variables like:

Crude representation:

```
{
    VAR1, a
    VAR1, b
    VAR2, c
    VAR1, d
    VAR3, e
    etc...
}
```

Then you can use multimap::equal_range() function to get a set of variables with the same "key", e.g. variables with key "VAR1".

I am not sure if there is a QMultimap, but there is definatley a QMap I have not looked. But if not just use the standard c++ multimap.

Comment: so far as I know from the performance point of view is QVector faster than QMap, so therefore I'm thinking more about QVector

Comment: @MiroKarpis In this case I am not sure that performance is better for vector. The multimap stores the elements sorted by 'key'. So when it needs to extract the elements with say 'equal_range()' function it can do it pretty quickly (faster then vector if there are many results to find). However vector is probably faster for adding / removing elements or accessing a single element by index... it depends where you want your performance to be optimised.... to me it looks like you want optimisation on getting the results out fast :)